# Pick from a union with different props

Tags: typescript

Let's say we have a type that is a union of two different shapes:

```js
type VERTICAL = {
    up: string
    down: string
}
type HORIZONTAL = {
    left: string
    right: string
}

type DIRECTIONS = VERTICAL | HORIZONTAL
```

I want to do something like:

```js
type TEST = DIRECTIONS["left"] // Property 'left' does not exist on type 'DIRECTIONS'.(2339)
```

and having TEST = string.

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAagogJQCoEkDCBBAMlAvFAbwFgAoKcqAVzAC4oBnYAJwEsA7Ac1IqgBMB7AO5s6jVp24UA9FKgAbCADNgdNpQC2AIwhNSAX1KhIUABIB5BCgBaZgHJJseQpPILlo5uy5kKrDgAsVBk8JEgMSQ3BoABEUBDg0VDsAZSd4ZHRHAB9TC2s7ByxSSOMkOGSkJ1j4xJQUgG0AIjdgRoBdUhkoI2gyioAmJzgAD2YAQwBjYAAeaoSk22SAGihmpVaAPk7ZHqg%20pABmJwAFFgmAa1m4%20brFlYJ5dboxthAoPQ2gA)

Some other requirements would be:

if `left` was present in `VERTICAL` too, let's say as `number`, TEST would be `string | number`.

if `left` wasn't present anyway, TEST would be `never`.

I know that this is not safe and can cause side effects, but I need this to type a function that accepts two parameters, and now it's always returning `never.`

Answer (score 0):

You have an **undiscriminable** union, meaning there is no way to determine which of the object it is with a single if

Try using

```
type XOR<T, V> = 
| T & {[K in Exclude<keyof V, keyof T>]?: never}
| V & {[K in Exclude<keyof T, keyof V>]?: never}

type DIRECTIONS = XOR<VERTICAL, HORIZONTAL>
type TEST = DIRECTIONS["left"]
// type TEST = string | undefined
```

for functions try

```
function foo<T extends HORIZONTAL | VERTICAL>(v: T){}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional type checks to extract the desired property from the union while considering the cases where it might not exist.

For that, we need a mapped type to iterate through the keys of the input type `T` and for each key, wz check if the corresponding value extends the desired type `U` (in this case, string).
 If it does, we include that key in the resulting type:

```js
type VERTICAL = {
    up: string;
    down: string;
    left?: number;
    right?: number;
};

type HORIZONTAL = {
    left: string;
    right: string;
    up?: number;
    down?: number;
};

type DIRECTIONS = VERTICAL | HORIZONTAL;

type ExtractKey<T, U> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type TEST = ExtractKey<DIRECTIONS, string>; // "left" | "right" | undefined
```

This should result in a union of keys that have values of the desired type.